# Statistical test to compare beta distributions between two groups

Tags: probability, beta-distribution

I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology but hopefully the code and plot will explain it well. I have six samples in two groups. Sample 1, 2 and 3 are in Group 1 and Sample 4,5,6 are in Group 2. All samples fit a beta distribution. I want to use a statistical test to explain the difference between the two groups and not just using the mean. Here's the code for it.

```
set.seed(123)
params <- list(c(1, 9), c(2, 18), c(3, 27), c(6, 4), c(9, 6), c(12, 8))
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = 500))
colnames(df) <- paste("Sample", 1:6, sep = "_")
for(i in 1:6) { df[,i] <- rbeta(500, params[[i]][1], params[[i]][2]) }
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use this above plot? To me, this is the most obvious way to show there's a difference.

Comment: @AlexJ The plot is just for one event, I have around 50000 events that I'll have to test; also I may have more samples per group as well. Sorting each event by a pvalue or f-stat would be ideal.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/betareg.pdf would reporting coefficients from Beta Regression do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the distributions are not normal, you could use the Mann-Whitney test, or the Wilcoxon rank sum test, which are almost identical.  These are non-parametric tests for which means and s.d.'s are not used but rather ranks, to test if $x$-values in the two groups are from the same distribution (null hypothesis, $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2 = \mathcal{D}$) or not from the same distribution (alternative hypothesis, $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2 \neq  \mathcal{D}$).